# ¿Por qué se denomina "panchitos" a las semillas de cacahuete fritas?

Tags: etimología, españa, comida

[**Panchito**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RdqXU1H) es

> Del dim. del n. p. *Pancho*.
>
> 1. m. Semilla de cacahuete frita, generalmente con sal.

Parece que la palabra se incorporó al Diccionario de la Lengua en 2001 como "*Cacahuete pelado y frito.*" y, consultando el CREA, parece utilizarse únicamente en España.

¿Cuál es el origen de esta denominación?

Comment: Alguna gente en España usa el término "panchito" para referirse (de forma despectiva) a las personas latinoamericanas. Me pregunto si el hecho de que los cacahuetes provengan del continente americano está relacionado de alguna manera.

Comment: Aparte, es la primera vez que escucho panchito para cacahuete/maní. Para mí los panchitos son los gusanitos de maíz con queso (los naranjas)... aunque creo que eso se debe a una marca

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro podría pasar como con el maíz frito, que en algunos lugares se conocen/conocían como "churrucas" por la marca comercial más habitual del producto.

Comment: Llamar _panchitos_ a los cacahuetes pelados y fritos es común en Madrid desde finales de los años 70. Su origen ? lo ignoro. Al resto de formas de presentar los cacahuetes se les llama simplemente _cacahuetes_, aunque hay zonas de España donde es más común llamarlos _manís_.

Answer (score 3):

En el siglo XIX en la zona de Madrid se denominaba "panchitos" a la gente de piel morena, en el sentido de piel curtida por el sol. He encontrado en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España un [artículo del 11 de septiembre de 1897](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002103129&page=6&search=panchitos&lang=es) cuyo título es *Morenos agraciados*, perteneciente a una sección titulada "Madrid cómico", que habla de la gente que vuelve blanca de las vacaciones de verano por no haber podido ir a la playa a tomar el sol:

> Cuesta cierto rubor en esta temporada presentarse á los amigos
>   que regresan, con la cara y las manos blancas, cuando ellos vuelven
>   *Panchitos del to*.
>        La blancura en estos días es patente de pobreza.

Conociendo esto, es fácil darse cuenta del símil: un cacahuete que ha sido tostado se pone moreno, y por tanto es un cacahuete *panchito*.

Comment: De hecho _panchitos_ se usa actualmente de forma un tanto despectiva en España para referirse a los hispanoamericanos, al menos en mi zona.